# How to implement get operations with different criteria for google cloud endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I am planning to use google cloud endpoints for my android app to communicate to the backend in order to query the database. Since the google cloud endpoints implements REST, it maps get, update, remove and insert uniquely. So, it only allows one method of each operation. In reality, the app needs more than one way of get. For example, getByLocation and getByRadius. Both of them are get operations, but they need different search criteria. In other words, I need a way to query the database with different criteria from the app. How can I implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to use parameters in your requests, like

```
/user?location=Boston&radius=10&sortBy=distance
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Endpoints you are not limited to basic REST methods:

> You are certainly not limited to those basic actions. Adding custom methods gives you much more flexibility, allowing you to perform complex operations. For example, checkForVictory might perform several queries, plus a write, to a database. https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/

You can have your methods like follow:

```
...
@ApiMethod(name = "getByLocation")
public SomeThing getByLocation(@Named("location" String location){
   //retrieve from datastore (use Objectify!)  
   return someThing; 
} 

@ApiMethod(name = "getByRadius")
public SomeThing getByRadius(@Named("radius" String radius){
   //retrieve from datastore (use Objectify!)  
   return someThing; 
}
```

Comment: But I get "Multiple methods with same rest path "GET site/{}": "getSite" and "getByLocation""

Comment: Did you have written exactly this: @ApiMethod(name = "getByLocation")?

Comment: Yes, it is. The error message is Error:Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: siteApi.com.example.myapplication.backend.SiteEndpoint: Multiple methods with same rest path "GET site/{}": "getByLocation" and "getSite"

Comment: By the way, what is the rule of naming if I need 3 GET method, getSite, getByLocation and getByRadius.

Comment: No rules. You can call your methods what you want. But you must annotate them differently. You must have @ApiMethod(name = "{UNIQUE_NAME}").

Comment: In ApiMethod, besides the name, there is a path to set. Just set different paths for all the get.